# Is there some way to read props from the server when _app loads

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

I want to create a dynamic nav menu based on my /pages directory to scan the folder and update menu links automatically as I add new files. I am trying this in stages.

Stage 1: I have created a standalone navbar page with its own getServerSideProps to read the file system and return /pages. This works fine.

Stage 2: I want this to load on every page but _app doesn't support its own getServerSideProps and Next js won't call getServerSideProps on my Navbar if I import it as part of my wrapper template into _apps.

Is there a way to create a shared component that loads with _app and can also read from the server?

Comment: Assuming all your pages will be SSRd, you can use `getInitialProps` in `_app` to perform server-side operations on all pages.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no approach of doing that directly inside the custom `_app` because, like your already mentioned `_app` does not support it's own `getServerSideProps`  (yet).

#### Possible approach

Your could use ISR so the server checks the directory periodically for changes, then when reading the contents of the `page` directory save the retrieved data as json to a file on the disk and import it back into the navbar component.